PhpStorm - List files with Warnings on specific php version
I have a bigger PHP project and it runs on production server with PHP 8.1.
To check the compatibility with 8.2 I switch to version 8.2 in PhpStorm.
If I open a file I can see any problems with the new version. It is possible to search for this problematic files to detect problems?


If you know the inspection name -- just Code | Analyze Code | Run Inspection by Name -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/running-inspections.html#run-one-inspection 2) You can find out the inspection name by looking at what you have in the Problems tool window (where all issues in the current file are reported) -- you can navigate to the actual inspection from there via the Quick Fix context menu (see the images of such a menu at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-in-editor for example)



if it's more than one inspection (e.g. 2-3 that check different aspects) -- create a custom Inspection Profile (where you have only desired inspections enabled) and run it manually on the desired scope: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/running-inspections.html#run-inspections-manually


Have you tried to upgrade yor project with rector php? It works like a charm and you can preview chages with --dry-run option. Here you are a blog entry about that task https://tech.osteel.me/posts/upgrade-your-project-to-the-latest-php-version-with-rector

My (limited) experience with Rector is that it attempts to use as many new features provided by newer version as possible, and I assume in this case we just want to address functionality that will no longer work.
